# #define in inline assembly in GCC

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, inline

I'm attempting to write inline assembly in GCC which writes a value in a #define to a register.

```
#define SOME_VALUE  0xDEADBEEF

void foo(void)
{
    __asm__("lis r5, SOME_VALUE@ha");
    __asm__("ori r5, r5, SOME_VALUE@l");
}
```

However, I get an error when I compile:

> undefined reference to `SOME_VALUE'

Is there a way for the assembler to see the `#define` in the inline assembly?

I've solved it by doing the following:

```
#define SOME_VALUE  0xDEADBEEF
__asm__(".equ SOME_VALUE,   0xDEADBEEF");

void foo(void)
{
    __asm__("lis r5, SOME_VALUE@ha");
    __asm__("ori r5, r5, SOME_VALUE@l");
}
```

However, I really don't want to duplicate the value.

Comment: As you can see, `__asm__` is taking a string as an argument. So think about macro stringifying the value/ concatenating strings.

Comment: Just FYI, your examples are completely unsafe.  If you're going to clobber a register, you need to use Extended asm with an output constraint.  And you should definitely put multiple instructions in the same asm statement; you shouldn't assume that the compiler will put your asm statements back to back.

Comment: So if you're using extended asm anyway, you can use constraints to ask for `SOME_VALUE` as an immediate on whatever architecture that is.  Or just ask the compiler to put it in `r5` for you, with `register int foo asm("r5") = SOME_VALUE;` and then use it as an input.  Or if you don't care what register, then let the compiler pick.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, it was just a dumb example.  I realize how unsafe it is.  But thank you for pointing it out.  Some one reading in the future may not realize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use some preprocessor magic for stringification of the value and the string continuation in C:

```
#define SOME_VALUE  0xDEADBEEF
#define STR(x) #x
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)

void foo(void)
{
    __asm__("lis r5, " XSTR(SOME_VALUE) "@ha");
    __asm__("ori r5, r5, " XSTR(SOME_VALUE) "@l");
}
```

`XSTR` will expand into the string `"0xDEADBEEF"`, which will get concatenated with the strings around it.

Here is the demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/2tBfoD

Comment: Yes, but this seems like an XY problem, because that inline asm steps on the compiler's registers.  See my comments on the question; using a numeric constant as an input constraint should work too as either an immediate / literal or as a register value.